# Error is thrown when using GET in a REST API client

Tags: c#, rest, get, webservice-client

I'm consuming a web service in REST, I'm using Windows Forms, C#.

When I am running the line

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse ();
```

I get an error

> InnerException = {" Cannot read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forced to close by the remote host. "}

If anyone can help me stay, I will be grateful.

Here is the code:

```cs
public string Get()
{
    string errorMessage;
    string StrResponseValue = string.Empty;
    try 
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(EndPoint);

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call! Program will wait here until a response is received or a timeout occurs.
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Parse the response body.
            var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<DataObject>>().Result;  // Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
            foreach (var d in dataObjects)
            {
            //  Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.Name);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }  
        client.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      errorMessage= ex.Message;
    }
    
    return StrResponseValue;
}
```

Comment: This is most likely the destination server refusing the connection because you're trying to connect with [a very old and obsolete version of TLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/engineering/solving-tls1-problem), but there isn't enough information in the question to be sure.

Comment: @CodeCaster  i updated the code and the error message, thank you

Comment: @TomW what do you need more please let me know, i updated the code and the error, thank you

Comment: Or maybe the site closes the connection because it doesn't like programmatic access, or because of missing cookies, or... Try setting a User-Agent header. Try comparing a working request from the browser with a non-working request from code, for example using Fiddler.

Comment: @CodeCaster  Well i tested the web service in Soap UI and it returned the values in Json, i add "client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("******", "**********");" too have my headers but still have the same problem

Comment: Did the code ever work???  The most common solution is to add following at beginning of the code : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: The problema was in the security protocol, thank all of you @jdweng